# How to delete too many Cloudformation stacks with status DELETE_COMPLETE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

At my current site there is a very large number of cloudformation stacks in one account.

If we make an AWS CLI call to list all stacks, we get an error message saying the request has been dynamically throttled, and the request fails.

As per AWS documentation advice to avoid dynamic throttling, I implemented a script to download in smaller chunks, using pagination and exponential delays.

This succeeded but if we could get rid of the many stacks in `DELETE_COMPLETE` status, this would remove around 800 stacks and the would complete successfully.

How can I remove AWS Cloudformation stacks that are in `DELETE_COMPLETE` status?

We are also seeing problems in the Cloudformation console with the simplest operations timing out due to the large number of stacks. A request has been raised with AWS for this. The console is useful for development and debugging although all our deployments are automated.

I found an old forum post saying these stacks will auto-delete after 90 days, but we have 800+ of these, some much older than that, and they are still there.

If I delete one of the stacks with a CLI call, like this:

`aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:123456789:stack/my-stack-name-here/87654321-1aaa-11aa-00a1-0aa1a0000000`

The delete call terminates with no errors but the stack remains as it was.
I can see the call has executed in Cloudtrail.
It looks like the `delete-stack` operation does nothing if the status is already set to `DELETE_COMPLETE`.

We need to delete these stacks because there are about 800 of them and we have so many stacks that the console is giving us errors for the simplest tasks, like searching for a stack to edit it.

We did increase the quota size (max number of stacks) via an AWS request but the throttling kicks in when we try to list them all, because there are so many of them.

Comment: I don't believe you can delete these, but they shouldn't cause any issues unless you are looking at 'Deleted' stacks in the console. Deleted stacks are not returned in the default 'Active' results. If you are seeing errors you should contact AWS support.

Comment: Ideally you'd be using automation rather than the AWS Console if you use CloudFormation a lot.

Comment: @Jason Wadsworth these are most definitely causing an issue - if we try to list all the stacks with the CLI, these are returned along with all the other stacks, and the throttling kills the request after a few seconds. I would add a screenprint here if I could, beleive me, this is not an imagined problem. We do have an abnormally high number of tacks due to an earlier architect having one stack per database table (!) this is what we are living with although we need to delete these this is the reality of the system now that has to be fixed.

Comment: @jarmod we use automation for all systems as standard. We are using the console here only to investigate further. The problem happens when we try to list the stacks using an AWS CLI script. Having said that there are some use cases where the console can be useful - for example when developing a new stack and debugging, to see what resources were created, error messages and the like.

Comment: Please tell me why this has been downvoted?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I found an old forum post saying they will auto-delete after 90 days

Deleted stack records expiring after a certain amount of time is currently the only way deleted stack records can be removed

> We have increased the quota size (max number of stacks) via an AWS request

[The quota for max number of stacks only applies to active stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html), so this is unrelated

> the throttling kicks in when use the console for ordinary actions because there are so many of them

The console has a stack status dropdown next to the search bar to filter by stack status

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you have a reference for this? ("expiry ... is the only way"?) e.g. AWS documentation.

It's true what you say about the quota size, we worked with AWS support to increase this to help the problem but it had no effect on the throttling.